# Reply to an email

Tags: grammar, meaning

I got an email from someone, it was supposed to have three receipt attached. But i only got two in the attachment, how should i notify sender.

Can i say,

> “no.xxx receipt was not found in the attachment.can you please resend.”

Is it correct and formal?

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Here are a few ways that you could communicate this:

- “*Receipt #2 was not in the attachments. Can you please resend it?*"
- "*Receipt no. 2 was not attached. Can you please resend it?*"
- "*I only received two of the three attachments. Can you please resend receipt #2?*"
- "*Receipt #2 was missing from the attachments. Can you resend it?*"
- "*Could you please resend receipt #2? It was not in the attachments.*"

A few things to keep in mind:

1) Make sure you mind your capitalization. The first word at the beginning of a sentence should be capitalized. While the meaning comes through clearly regardless of capitalization, if you want your writing to appear professional, proper capitalization is very important.

2) Although you'd be understood, and there is nothing formally wrong with it, I would suggest saying *"Can you please resend **it**?"* instead of just *"Can you please resend?"*

3) If you are going to use the abbreviation *"no."* for number , make sure you put a space between the period and the number. So use *"no. 2"* not *"no.2"*. Likewise, put at least one space following the period at the end of the sentence, before beginning the next sentence.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine you just forgot the word "it" at the end of your sentence, but I'll give a second alternative in case you want to say it a little different.

> Hi there. I've only got 2 of the 3 receipts you were supposed to
>   send me, could you please resend receipt number ####? Much
>   appreciated, thanks.